# OpenSSL verify: missing flag "-allow_proxy_certs"

Tags: openssl, proxy, certificates

OS: Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty

Openssl version: OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014

I'm trying to verify a proxy certificate.
If I use

```
openssl verify -CAfile myca.pem mycert.pem
```

I obtain this error:

```
error 40 at 0 depth lookup:proxy certificates not allowed, please set the appropriate flag
```

This is because "mycert.pem" is a proxy certificate, so I have to declare it to openssl.

The right way to do it is to add this command:

```
-allow_proxy_certs
```

as written in [Openssl verify: Man Page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/verify.html)

But when I add -allow_proxy_certs command like this:

```
openssl verify -allow_proxy_certs -CAfile myca.pem mycert.pem
```

it prints

```
usage: verify [-verbose] [-CApath path] [-CAfile file] [-purpose purpose] [-crl_check] [-no_alt_chains] [-attime timestamp] [-engine e] cert1 cert2 ...
```

That is the same output I get calling

```
openssl verify -help
```

So it seems "-allow_proxy_certs" is missing in my openssl version. How could I add it and use it?

Comment: Looks like you need a version from July this year or newer.  https://mta.openssl.org/pipermail/openssl-commits/2016-June/008721.html

Answer (score 1):

After [Mikel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/3169/mikel)'s comment, I resolved the issue.

1) I've downloaded that openssl version from [their github page](https://github.com/openssl/openssl)

2) I've followed the instructions written in INSTALL file (using "./config --prefix=/usr/" instead of "./config")

3) after installation, "openssl version" gave me the correct output with new openssl version. Command "--allow_proxy_cert" can be now used.